# How to implement a circuit preparing the three-qubit W state?

Tags: quantum-state, w-state

I'm trying to implement a circuit wich prepare this three qubits state :
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(|100\rangle + |010\rangle + |001\rangle)$

It seems that the three qubits W-state can produce this state, and I found this [code](https://notebook.community/antoniomezzacapo/qiskit-tutorial/community/teach_me_qiskit_2018/w_state/W%20State%201%20-%20Multi-Qubit%20Systems).

But I have seen a simple circuit [on this page](https://medium.com/transilvaniaquantum/simulating-the-monty-hall-problem-on-a-quantum-computer-71613f54f0bf) wich seems to work, but I don't understand how the person find the Ry rotation of 1.321, does someone could explain me how 1.321 is found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because $RY(1.321)$ put the qubit from the state $|\psi_0\rangle = |0\rangle$ to the state $|\psi_1 \rangle = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}} |0\rangle + \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{3}} |1\rangle $. One of the thing to note here is also that $RY$ is rotating around the $Y$ axis so it is the rotation gate that we want to use if we want to keep the amplitude of the quantum state real.

[image]

From there you can work out the rest of the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading this article:

[Effient quantum algorithms for GHZ and W states, and implementation on the IBM Q](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.05572).

It provides general algorithm for constructing a circuit producing W-state with arbitrary number of qubits.

Here is a code based on the article:

```
def _w_state_circuit(circuit, nn, mm, qubitC):    
    global qubitT #reference to global variable qubitT
    
    if nn == 0 and mm == 1:
        pass #do nothing in this case
    elif nn == 1 and mm == 2: #case (1,2)
        circuit.cu3(m.pi/2, 0, 0, q[qubitC], q[qubitT])
        circuit.cx(q[qubitT], q[qubitC])
        qubitT = qubitT + 1
    else: #otherwise
        theta = 2*np.arccos(m.sqrt(nn/mm))
        circuit.cu3(theta, 0, 0, q[qubitC], q[qubitT])
        circuit.cx(q[qubitT], q[qubitC])
        
        qubitTRecurse = qubitT #saving target qubit index, used as control qubit for lower child
        qubitT = qubitT + 1
        
        a = m.floor(nn/2)
        b = m.floor(mm/2)
        c = m.ceil(nn/2)
        d = m.ceil(mm/2)
        
        if a == 1 and b == 1: #upper child (1,1) => (1,2) became upper child
            circuit = _w_state_circuit(circuit, 1, 2, qubitC)
            #there is no lower child
        elif c == 1 and d == 1: #lower child (1,1) => (1,2) became lower child
            circuit = _w_state_circuit(circuit, 1, 2, qubitTRecurse)
            #there is no upper child
        else:                       
            #upper child
            circuit = _w_state_circuit(circuit, a, b, qubitC)                 
            #lower child
            circuit = _w_state_circuit(circuit, c, d, qubitTRecurse)
                
    return circuit
        
def w_state_circuit (qubits, qRegister, cRegister):
    global qubitT
    qubitT = 1 #index of a qubit a new gate acts on (hard to compute inside recursion => global variable)
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(qRegister, cRegister)
    circuit.x(q[0])
    circuit = _w_state_circuit(circuit, m.floor(qubits/2), qubits, 0)
    return circuit

#construction of 6 qubits W-state
qubits = 6

q = QuantumRegister(qubits, name = 'q')
c = ClassicalRegister(qubits, name = 'c')

circuit = w_state_circuit(qubits, q, c)

circuit.draw()
```

Comment: What do "mm", "nn" and "m" represent in the above code.

Comment: @rabahhacenebenaissa: m is an abbrev for Math library in Python which should be imported. Other variables refer to nodes in a tree used in construction of W state, see the linked article for details.